# PHPMailer: Erro ao enviar de servidor Linux

Tags: php, html, linux

Configurei uma página HTML para enviar e-mail com o PHPMailer, e no meu computador com Windows 10 ela enviou normalmente, mas no servidor online em Linux retorna o erro de SMTP:
" SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"

Acredito que seja uma variável de segurança ou de porta, mas não sei qual delas devem ser alteradas.

Comment: Seria bom [edit] e por o log de erros do PHPMailer para poder determinar a causa exata

Comment: Bacco como posso verificar o log de erros?

Comment: Se fizer uma página contendo apenas `<? phpinfo();` deve ver várias configurações do servidor ao acessar, uma delas é a diretiva error log, que aponta o local correto. Dependendo da hospedagem, tem que pedir acesso. Note nos posts acima (ou na documentação), algum deles provavelmente diz também como ligar o modo debug do phpmailer, isso pode ajudar